# Why can we only initialize structs with primitive types or pointers?

Tags: c++

```cpp
class MyClass {
};

struct myStruct {
    MyClass instance;
};

struct myStructReference {
    MyClass& instance;
};

struct myStructPointer {
    MyClass* instance;
};

int main() {
  // EDIT: works!
  myStruct b;

  // also doesn't work
//   myStructReference c;

  // works
  myStructPointer d;
}
```

The error I get is: `'myStructReference::myStructReference()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:`.

It appears as though C++ goes through the motions of creating a default constructor for a struct, but then fails. I suppose this makes sense, since a struct is nearly identical to a class under the hood, just struct has all default public members + inheritance.

Is it because we can automatically assign a pointer to initialize as `NULL`, whereas we can't with a reference?

Asking to learn!

Comment: `myStruct b;` should work. Test it again.

Comment: ah, correct you are. edited! but how is `myStruct` different from `myStructReference`? this might be a dumb question.

Comment: Well, the second one has a reference member and the first doesn't.

Comment: myStructReference has a reference member, and references must be initialized at the moment they're created.

Comment: @interjay so the difference is that the reference member allocates only a small amount of memory inside the struct, while the instance member may potentially have a lot of memory allocated (all the things within MyClass instance)?

Comment: @TonyTannous this might seem like a silly question but why must references be initialized at moment of creation? with pointers we do not.

Comment: @lollercoaster Because the language rules say so. A reference must always be initialized and the object a reference references can never be changed. That is the main difference to a pointer. If references worked exactly the same way as pointers, there would be no point in having them in the language.

Comment: @lollercoaster -- There is no such thing in C++ as an uninitialized reference.

Comment: You can use `myStructReference` like this: `MyClass mc; myStructReference c{mc};` Now the reference is initialized properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myStructReference::instance` is, well, a reference. References MUST always be initialized. In this case, you reference is not initialized, so it won't compile.

Comment: Why must references always be initialized?

Comment: @lollercoaster Because the C++ standard says so. Otherwise, it would not reference anything valid, and that would be just as dangerous as using an uninitialized pointer.  A reference is an *alias* to something, it can't alias *nothing*. Remember, C++ originally came from C, and references were new in C++, they don't exist in C. They are meant to help you replace the use of (potentially unsafe) pointers.

Comment: interesting - do you know of any good reading or resources on this? just curious about the under-the-hood implementation & history of references vs pointers.

Comment: @lollercoaster, here https://youtu.be/XS2JddPq7GQ?t=1129 ... there are many good videos in this channel for improving your C++ skills ;-)